# Problem with expo-video-player, it throws Error: setAudioModeAsync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, video, expo

I have a problem with 'expo-video-player' package. I want to show a video through expo-video-player but when I load the component it throws an error and I don't know how to resolve it, so I need help..

I've tried change the package source code and the component props but it doesn't works

Here is the code: (Example code from expo-video-player)

```
import { Video } from 'expo'
import VideoPlayer from 'expo-video-player'

<VideoPlayer
 videoProps={{
 shouldPlay: true,
 resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN,
 source: {
   uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
  },
 }}
 isPortrait={true}
 playFromPositionMillis={0}
/>
```

Here is the error:

> Error: , setAudioModeAsync error, 1, [Error: Audio mode attempted to be set without the required keys: ["staysActiveInBackground"]]
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
>   - node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
>   - ... 17 more stack frames from framework internals

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the module?

Comment: Yes, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the module

Comment: I would like to know as well. I started getting this error lately (may be since yesterday). It was working fine last week. I haven't changed anything the video player component.

Comment: reffer link https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/sdk/audio/#returns-1

Answer (score 1):

This issue was created by Expo SDK 33, where some modules has been removed from the core.

Upgrade to the latest version (`1.3.0`). It is fixed here.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-video-player