# Getting 'setAudioModeAsync error' from expo-video-player

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I try to load a video from my phone on the VideoPlayer and I get some error by Audio even though I am not using audio at all. All I am using is Video from 'expo-av'.
Here is the error:

`Error:, setAudioModeAsync error, 1, [Error: Audio mode attempted to be set without the required keys: ["staysActiveInBackground"]] Below is the code.`

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react- 
native';
import {Video} from "expo";
import VideoPlayer from "expo-video-player";

export default class App extends Component {
render() {
// return <AppContainer />;
return(
    <View>
      <VideoPlayer
          videoProps={{
            shouldPlay: true,
            isLooping: true,
            resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN,
            source: {
              uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
            },
          }}
          isPortrait={true}
          playFromPositionMillis={0}
      />

    </View>
);
}}
```

Comment: `Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ staysActiveInBackground : true })`

Comment: But why would I need that since I am not even importing Audio in my project? Also, would I do that in componentDidMount?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was created by Expo SDK 33, where some modules has been removed from the core.

Upgrade to the latest version (1.3.0). It is fixed here.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-video-player

*Duplicate question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827764/problem-with-expo-video-player-it-throws-error-setaudiomodeasync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827764/problem-with-expo-video-player-it-throws-error-setaudiomodeasync_)*